# Cannot Compile WordCount.java

Tags: java, javac, cloudera, word-count

```
mark@maestro1:/usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes$ javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar -d /usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes /usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes/WordCount.java
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar(org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.class):     
warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'LimitedPrivate': class file for org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience not found
/usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes/WordCount.java:14: error: error while writing Map: could not create parent directories
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
            ^
1 error
1 warning
```

what is with this error? I cannot compile this wordcount.java file!

People have been telling me to set my java classpath correctly. Would anyone have any comment on how I go about this as well? Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some of the code... There are clearly mistakes. Set classpath: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
-d /usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes
```

indicates where you want the class files written. Is this correct ? I suspect you don't have permission to write there, hence:

```
error while writing Map: could not create parent directories
```

Can you create a directory in that directory (hint: use `mkdir`) ? I don't think the `/usr/lib` directory is a good place to do this, btw, even if you can. I would expect you to perform development within your home directory.

The /usr directory is usually used for installations of programs, libraries etc. and write-restricted for normal users. `man hier` gives a good explanation of the different directories used in Unix.

Comment: Thanks ! That helped with the could not create parent directories! I changed it to a new folder called wordcount that is located in ~. Now why do i still get 1 warning? Here is what I got:

Comment: mark@maestro1:~$ javac -classpath /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop/client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar -d ~/wordcount /usr/lib/hadoop/wordcount_classes/WordCount.java
/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.0.1.jar(org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.class): warning: Cannot find annotation method 'value()' in type 'LimitedPrivate': class file for org.apache.hadoop.classification.InterfaceAudience not found
1 warning

Comment: @user1663321 - that's perhaps a different question more related to Hadoop. Glad the dir stuff worked