# Building hadoop plugin using eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I am building hadoop plugin using Eclipse
The hadoop version is 1.0.4
When I use ant builder, I got error as follows

```
compile:
 [echo] contrib: eclipse-plugin
[javac] /home/shijieru/Downloads/HadoopInstall/hadoop-1.0.4/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/build.xml:61: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
[javac] Compiling 45 source files to /home/shijieru/Downloads/HadoopInstall/hadoop-1.0.4/build/contrib/eclipse-plugin/classes
[javac] /home/shijieru/Downloads/HadoopInstall/hadoop-1.0.4/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/eclipse/Activator.java:28: error: error while writing Activator: could not create parent directories
[javac] public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
[javac]        ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
/home/shijieru/Downloads/HadoopInstall/hadoop-1.0.4/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin/build.xml:61: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Could anyone tell me what probably is the cause of these problem?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is not specific to hadoop, but directory permissions - 'could not create parent directories' is output by javac - make sure you have appropriate permissions for the bin directories you are compiling to.

(Based on similar question with the same error message: [Cannot Compile WordCount.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514867/cannot-compile-wordcount-java))